# How do i place an element on the right of other elements in a div?

Tags: html, css

So I want to place my button to look like this :

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5ghV.png)

But I don't know what I should do to make it work, this is my HTML code :

```
<div  class="content" *ngIf="loading==false" >
      <div class="product" *ngFor="let product of products$ | async ; let i = index">
        <div class="header">
        <h1 class="product-name">Product name : {{product.Name}}</h1>
        <h2 class="product-id">Product id : {{product.Id}} </h2>
        <button (click)="addCanvasModel(product.Id)">Add new Canvas Model</button>
      </div>
      <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="3px grid">
        <div *ngFor="let model of myObservables[i] | async"> 
          <app-bmc-card-preview [name]="model.Designation" [id]="model.Id" [behaviour_subject]="refreshModels$"></app-bmc-card-preview>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
</div>
```

and this is my CSS code :

```
.product {
    background-color: white;
    border:1px solid black;
    font-family: roboto;
    text-align: left;
    margin:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flex`:

```
<div class="content" *ngIf="loading==false">
    <div class="product" *ngFor="let product of products$ | async ; let i = index">
        <div class="header" style="display:flex;">
            <div style="flex:1;">
                <h1 class="product-name">Product name : {{product.Name}}</h1>
                <h2 class="product-id">Product id : {{product.Id}} </h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button (click)="addCanvasModel(product.Id)">Add new Canvas Model</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="3px grid">
            <div *ngFor="let model of myObservables[i] | async">
                <app-bmc-card-preview [name]="model.Designation" [id]="model.Id" [behaviour_subject]="refreshModels$"></app-bmc-card-preview>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: click on gray tick aside of codes in this answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<div  class="content" *ngIf="loading==false" >
    <div class="product" *ngFor="let product of products$ | async ; let i = index">
            <div class="header">
               <div class="container"> 
                   <h1 class="product-name">Product name : {{product.Name}}</h1>
                    <h2 class="product-id">Product id : {{product.Id}} </h2>
                </div>
            <button (click)="addCanvasModel(product.Id)">Add new Canvas Model</button>
          </div>
          <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="3px grid">
            <div *ngFor="let model of myObservables[i] | async"> 
              <app-bmc-card-preview [name]="model.Designation" [id]="model.Id" [behaviour_subject]="refreshModels$"></app-bmc-card-preview>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      
    </div>
    
    .product {
        background-color: white;
        border:1px solid black;
        font-family: roboto;
        text-align: left;
        margin:10px;
        display:flex;
    }
    .container{
        display:block;
    }
```